# Writing a program that will automate searches on finra.org for brokers

Tags: java

So I have two possible solutions that I want to implement. Firstly I will state my problem. The task I have been assigned to requires me to go to a website called finra.org and do broker checks to see if the brokers in my excel sheet(which gives the name and company among other things) still work A, and if they do work do they still work for the company in the excel sheet. If they do move on to the next one, and if they don't delete them from the sheet. The issue lies in that I have 37k names to check. I calculated this and to do it individually, which is annoying and takes the whole day allows me to do a maximum of 1400 a day. That is on a productive day when I dont have other things to do. So I figured a better use of my time ( I am an intern) would be to write a program which (here are my two suggested solutions:)

1.) Automatically through minimal key strokes copies the data and pastes it into the search box on the page. Ill still have to click and search but at least I would eliminate copying and pasting and switching between screens which takes the majority of the time.

2.) Completely automate the process. I was thinking of copying the names into a text file and then somehow writing a program that takes each name and submits a query to this website which would then show me the result. Perhaps sends the result text to a text file and then i could just GREP the text file for the data that i need.

Any idea if any of this is possible?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Yes, it all sounds straight forward. I am surprised FINRA don't provide an API. ;)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But finding someone to write the whole program (or shell script) for you is out of scope of this site. If you started to write it and had problems, this is the place to find answers. Search for "web scraping" here to get started.

Comment: For starters, I'd suggest exporting the Excel file to CSV. It's a lot easier to parse with most languages.

Comment: The [Legal Notices](http://www.finra.org/Legal/) state in part: *"..may not be copied, reproduced, transmitted, displayed, performed, distributed, rented, sublicensed, altered, stored for subsequent use or otherwise used in whole or in part in any manner without FINRA's prior written consent.."*  When you are writing to them about their consent, ask them about the API that Peter mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible. I'm doing something similar with a database and an Excel spreadsheet of values using AutoHotKey to automate queries, Chrome console commands and Javascript bookmarklets to scrape data into the clipboard, and Ruby/Nokogiri with more complex and/or structured parsing tasks.

Either of your methods will work - if you have little programming background, I would suggest starting with AutoHotKey since it mimics keyboard and mouse commands, so the programming is much more straightforward and easier to understand. If you have some object-oriented programming skills, learning Ruby/Nokogiri *might* be your solution, depending on how FINRA's page is structued.